# Cannot retrieve Custom Taxonomies (Disappeared)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I was deleting custom posts from backend (wordpress dashboard). I have made a front-end form for a custom post type, it has check boxes for custom taxonomies. Now the taxonomies are not being fetched in the front-end. :( Please help.

I don't know if this is a word press cache issue or something else. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

**The Custom taxonomies in front-end which are no longer fetch-able**
[image: The Custom taxonomies in front-end which are no longer fetch-able]

**But are visible in the back-end**

[image: But are visible in the back-end]

Comment: *I was just deleting certain data of my custom post type.* What data exactly

Comment: @Pieter Goosen - sorry, i had posted in quite a hurry. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was pretty simple.Had I read WP documentation thoroughly for `get_categories`

Apparently I had to set this `'hide_empty' => false` when I fetched my taxonomies :)